# How do I dynamically invoke a Command's Subcommands Multiple Times?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

My Click 7.0 application has one group, having multiple commands, called by the main cli function like so:

#### Code:

```
import sys
import click

@click.group()
def cli():
    """This is cli helptext"""
    click.echo('cli called')

@cli.group(chain=True, no_args_is_help=False)
@click.option('-r', '--repeat', default=1, type=click.INT, help='repeat helptext')
def chainedgroup(repeat):
    """This is chainedgroup helptext"""

    top = sys.argv[2]
    bottom = sys.argv[3:]
    click.echo('chainedgroup code called')

    for _ in range(repeat):
        chainedgroup.main(bottom, top, standalone_mode=False)

@chainedgroup.command()
def command1():
    """This is command1 helptext"""
    click.echo('command1 called')

@chainedgroup.command()
@click.option('-o', '--option')
def command2(option):
    """This is command2 helptext"""
    click.echo('command2 called with {0}'.format(option))
```

#### Run:

```
$ testcli chainedgroup --repeat 2 command1
$ testcli chainedgroup -r 3 command1 command2 -o test
```

#### Expected Result:

```
cli called
chainedgroup code called
command1 called
command1 called
----------
cli called
chainedgroup code called
command1 called
command2 called with test
command1 called
command2 called with test
command1 called
command2 called with test
```

#### Actual Result:

Case #1 gives me a `Missing command` error, while case #2 ends in a `RecursionError`.

<s>I'm sure</s> I was sure [`Command.main()`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/?highlight=types#click.BaseCommand.main) is the correct method to call. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: @StephenRauch Edited. In short, i'm looking for a way to safely call a group's (chained) subcommands as often as I'd like--**after** running arbitrary code in its  function first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a custom `click.Group` class you can override the `invoke()` method to call the commands more than once.

#### Custom Class:

```
class RepeatMultiCommand(click.Group):
    def invoke(self, ctx):
        old_callback = self.callback

        def new_callback(*args, **kwargs):
            # only call the group callback once
            if repeat_number == 0:
                return old_callback(*args, **kwargs)
        self.callback = new_callback

        # call invoke the desired number of times
        for repeat_number in range(ctx.params['repeat']):
            new_ctx = copy.deepcopy(ctx)
            super(RepeatMultiCommand, self).invoke(new_ctx)

        self.callback = old_callback
```

#### To use the Custom Class:

Pass the `.group()` decorator the custom class with the `cls` parameter like:

```
@cli.group(chain=True, no_args_is_help=False, cls=RepeatMultiCommand)
@click.option('-r', '--repeat', default=1, type=click.INT,
              help='repeat helptext')
def chainedgroup(repeat):
    ....
```

#### How does this work?

This works because click is a well designed OO framework. The `@click.group()` decorator usually instantiates a `click.Group` object but allows this behavior to be over ridden with the `cls` parameter. So it is a relatively easy matter to inherit from `click.Group` in our own class and over-ride the desired methods.

In this case, we override `click.Group.invoke()`.  In our `invoke()`, we hook the group callback so that we can have it only be called once, and we then call the `super().invoke()` a `repeat` number of times.

#### Test Code:

```
import click
import copy
import sys

@click.group()
def cli():
    """This is cli helptext"""
    click.echo('cli called')


@cli.group(chain=True, no_args_is_help=False, cls=RepeatMultiCommand)
@click.option('-r', '--repeat', default=1, type=click.INT,
              help='repeat helptext')
def chainedgroup(repeat):
    """This is chainedgroup helptext"""
    click.echo('chainedgroup code called')


@chainedgroup.command()
def command1():
    """This is command1 helptext"""
    click.echo('command1 called')


@chainedgroup.command()
@click.option('-o', '--option')
def command2(option):
    """This is command2 helptext"""
    click.echo('command2 called with {0}'.format(option))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        'chainedgroup --repeat 2 command1',
        'chainedgroup -r 3 command1 command2 -o test',
        'chainedgroup command1',
        'chainedgroup --help',
        '--help',
    )

    import sys, time

    time.sleep(1)
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    for cmd in commands:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + cmd)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            cli(cmd.split())

        except BaseException as exc:
            if str(exc) != '0' and \
                    not isinstance(exc, (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
                raise
```

#### Results:

```
Click Version: 6.7
Python Version: 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
-----------
> chainedgroup --repeat 2 command1
cli called
chainedgroup code called
command1 called
command1 called
-----------
> chainedgroup -r 3 command1 command2 -o test
cli called
chainedgroup code called
command1 called
command2 called with test
command1 called
command2 called with test
command1 called
command2 called with test
-----------
> chainedgroup command1
cli called
chainedgroup code called
command1 called
-----------
> chainedgroup --help
cli called
Usage: test.py chainedgroup [OPTIONS] COMMAND1 [ARGS]... [COMMAND2
                            [ARGS]...]...

  This is chainedgroup helptext

Options:
  -r, --repeat INTEGER  repeat helptext
  --help                Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  command1  This is command1 helptext
  command2  This is command2 helptext
-----------
> --help
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  This is cli helptext

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  chainedgroup  This is chainedgroup helptext
```

Comment: Note: If your `ctx.obj` contains any open files/serial connections/etc., you'll need to use the `ctx.command.make_context()` function to create the `new_ctx`copy